# Question about $\{1, \sqrt{3}\}$ being a basis of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$ over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

In Gallian's Abstract Algebra, he uses an example of $\{1, \sqrt{3}\}$ being a basis of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$ over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$ and $\{1, \sqrt{5}\}$ being a basis of $\Bbb Q(1, \sqrt{5})$ over $\Bbb Q$.

Why is $\{1, \sqrt{3}\}$ a basis of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$ over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5})$?  I don't really understand what $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$ is as a set and how I would form a basis from it.  I know that $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5}) = \{a_0 + a_1 \sqrt{5} : a_i \in \Bbb Q \}$, but for multiple "argument" extension fields I don't understand how they'd be written.

Comment: $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{3}, \sqrt{5})$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5}$. Its degree over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $4$, but over $\mathbb{Q}$ it is $2$. So the basis must have $2$ elements. We have $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)$.

Comment: If you know that $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5}) \simeq \mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^2-5)$ then in the same way $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{3}) =\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})(\sqrt{3})$ $ \simeq \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})[y]/(y^2-3)$ (since $y^2-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$) so that $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5},\sqrt{3}) :  \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})]= 2$ and a basis is ...

Comment: But what is $\Bbb Q(\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{3})$ in set notation?  What do elements of this set look like?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$a + b \sqrt{3} + c \sqrt{5} + d \sqrt{3}\sqrt{5}=(a+c \sqrt{5}) + (b+d\sqrt{5}) \sqrt{3}$$

Comment: the comments are made for that

Comment: What set does this represent?

Comment: The left side of the equation represents any number belonging to $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{5})$. The right side is the same number written as a member of $(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{5}))(\mathbb Q(\sqrt{3}))$